# MS SQL Return all rows after last instance of N

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS SQL query that returns a list of steps performed by a computer. It has the step number ordered by the time each step was performed. My problem is that sometimes the steps are repeated, but I only want to return the last sequence of steps 1->n. So I would like to take the last row with step 1 and only return that row and anything after.

```
SELECT Time,Step FROM Table1 
WHERE Computer = 'ComputerName'
AND Step IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Time
```

Info returned is...

```
Time   Step
00:01  1
00:02  2
00:03  3
00:04  1
00:05  2
00:06  3
00:07  4
```

I want to ignore everything before the last sequence of step 1->n and only return...

```
Time   Step
00:04  1
00:05  2
00:06  3
00:07  4
```

The steps will always start with 1, but the number of steps can vary. The number or repeats can also vary from not at all to any number of times.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MAX(Time) gave me an idea and i believe i figured it out. I just need to use a WHERE statement to get everything after the time the latest step 1 was performed.

```
SELECT Time,Step FROM Table1
WHERE Computer = 'Computer1'
AND Step IS NOT NULL
AND TIME >= (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM Table1 WHERE Computer = 'Computer1' AND Step = 1)
ORDER BY Time
```

Comment: This one makes the most sense to me too.

Comment: This one does not comply with your original question. If step 3 has occurred before step 2, step 3 won't show.

Comment: What would cause step 3 to not show? This should return anything that occurred after the most recent step 1.

Comment: Step 1 @ 01, step 2 @ 02, step 3@ 03, step 1@ 04, Step 2 @ 05 won't display step 3 @ 03 with this code.

Comment: Ah, ok, i see what you are saying. As i mentioned in my question the number of steps can vary and i am only looking for the last sequence. So whether it is step 1 to step 2, or step 1 to step 9000, all i want is the last 1 to N where N is the last step in the last sequence. I appreciate the heads up though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subquery and join -

```
SELECT MAX(Time), Step
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Step
```

Comment: This seems to return all steps and their last time ran. What i would like to return is the last 1,2,3,etc... So I'm trying to find the last instance of step 1, then return only that step and anything after, nothing before it. If the first run went to step 5, but the last only went to step 3 i don't care about the 4 and 5, just that last run of 1,2,3.

Comment: I expected better after dissing out on execution plan that wouldn't matter after a relatively small dataset anyway. Normalize.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT distinct t2.time, t1.step
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (Select MAX(time) time, step 
      FROM table1 
      GROUP BY step) as t2 ON t2.step = t1.step
ORDER BY step
```

[image: ExecutionPlan]

Comment: Subquery and Join are overkill - it is fine for this small table, but any large number of steps will take exponentially longer than a simple GROUP BY and MAX without it.

Comment: I might have over complicated my thinking. But this train of thought I believe is necessary due to the restrictions stated in the question; Steps can be restarted and only the last occurrence is required. Thanks for the downvote! ;)